# Load properties before a test

Tags: selenium

I am writing a set of tests to perform equivalency of web pages. The only differences (declaratively in the test) are the URLs.  I'd like to do this by somehow performing multiple store text commands prior to a test so that I can use the stored properties later within the testpage. Is there a clean way to do this?

old properties file

```
login.page=Login.jsp
```

new properties file

```
login.page=/new/Login
```

And the tests looks like:

```
.. do some storetexts ..
open | /mypagehome/${login.page}
```

- Sorry to clarify: I have 2 selenium tests for each page. These two tests are exactly the same with the exception of the url. One test the old site , one test the new one. Id like to only have one test and be able to point it to different instances of the site, i cant just use the 'base url' because the urls for both sites are significantly different. How do i get round this problem?

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand now! :-)

Selenium lets you open absolute URLs instead of just URLs that are relative to the base URL, so you could use something like this:

```
open | http://somedomain/mypage/${loginpage}
```